# SSO Bad Data Error

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm running BizTalk 2013r2 CU5 in Win2012r2

I noticed a file wasn't being collected from a receive location. The relevant host instance was running, so I checked the event log and found this:

> SSO AUDIT  Function: GetConfigInfo
>   ({E182FB76-16B4-47D7-8178-4C66C9E3BA9D})  Tracking ID:
>   c4d0d0d1-0763-4ec5-99ea-fb2ac3bcc744  Client Computer: BizTalkBuild01
>   (BTSNTSvc64.exe:7940)  Client User: BIZTALKBUILD01\BizTalkSvc 
>   Application Name: {E182FB76-16B4-47D7-8178-4C66C9E3BA9D}  Error Code:
>   0xC0002A1F, Cannot perform encryption or decryption because the secret
>   is not available from the master secret server. See the event log for
>   related errors.

I then restored the master secret using:

ssoConfig -restoresecret SSOxxxx.bak

After restoring, the file is still not being collected but the error messages in the event log have changed to this:

> SSO AUDIT  Function: GetConfigInfo
>   ({2DC11892-82FF-4617-A491-5324CAEF8E90})  Tracking ID:
>   5e91d09d-1128-491b-851b-e8c8e69d06eb  Client Computer: BizTalkBuild01
>   (BTSNTSvc64.exe:26408)  Client User: BIZTALKBUILD01\BizTalkSvc 
>   Application Name: {2DC11892-82FF-4617-A491-5324CAEF8E90}  Error Code:
>   0x80090005, Bad Data.

Does anyone know of a solution to this please? This is the 2nd time I've faced this problem on different servers in the last 3 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSI for CU6 has now been fixed

Answer (score 0):

For BizTalk 2013 R2 this may be a known issue, with a hotfix available!

There is a hotfix for this issue, however, the hotfix may introduce another issue (memory leak). A solution can be found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amantaras/2015/11/10/event-id-10536-entsso-bad-data-issue/

Comment: Thanks Pieter but I had seen that post. I didn't want to be installing individual hit fixes so I turned to CU6 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44238003/41169 As you can see, there I hit another brick wall!