# Can't Install BizTalk 2013r2 CU6

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm trying to install CU6 for BTS2013r2

I run the exe, it unpacks then starts the wizard. It progresses or a while then presents the following message:

[image]

I have the BizTalk ISO already downloaded from MSDN and mounted to the local server. So I browse to the correct path. Notice how the "File name:" text box of the select dialog has the filename miss-spelled as "aptersSetup.msi":
[image]

I ignore this miss-spelling and select the "AdaptersSetup.msi" from the ISO image. I then get the following error:

[image]

The wizard then backs-out the install of the AdapterPack and I run through the same problems for the "AdaptersSetup64.msi"

It seems impossible to install CU6 - anyone know of a work-around?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this one?

Comment: Not yet but Tord is on the case!

Comment: Yes, I saw his response.   At least one client of my company is installing CU6 this month.   I'm hoping we don't hit the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I will update here as soon as I know. My guess is there's something strange about the VMs I've been trying to update. I don't really believe that it impossible to install CU6!

Comment: Very possible in fact.  It has been successfully installed in one of our clients VM Dev environments and going to be deployed today into another VM Dev environment.  So yes, that must be something unique about your VM that is causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update this. Tord replied a couple of weeks ago. They did have a problem with the CU6 msi which they later replaced. I've re downloaded and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft have now fixed the CU6 MSI